# Spawning enemy at random spawn points without Overlapping![Not spawning]

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, random, spawn, overlapping

Hi stackoverflow's Members, This my first question...

I want to spawn Enemies at random spawn points without overlapping. So, I'm checking that if the spawn point is used then don't use that spawn point, if it's not then continue... I've an empty gameObject which contains all spawnPoints for enemy. I've assigned the script to that empty gameobejct.

**I tried to use Transform as a List for Spawn points but unfortunately, it didn't work. If you can convert this from Vector3 to Transform then, it'll be good. I tried to convert this in Transform but I got so many error. I did try, but, it didn't work as expected.**

You can check that script here:
[Transform error script](https://textuploader.com/149oh)

I got these errors:
[Transform errors](https://ibb.co/4fpNw8F)

**Now,** The script which I'm working on is as follow:

```
using UnityEngine;

 public GameObject enemy; //my enemy
 public float spawnTime = 3f; //spawn after 3 sec
 public List<Vector3> spawnPoints = new List<Vector3> (); //Vector3 positions of spawnpoints.
 public float distance;   //distance from the spawnPoints



 void Start ()
 {
     //spawnRandom ();
     InvokeRepeating ("spawnRandom", spawnTime, spawnTime); //Call this fucntion after 3sec.
 }

 public Vector3 spawnRandom(){

     Vector3 newSpawnPoint;  //new spawn point 
     Vector3 random = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * distance;

     newSpawnPoint = new Vector3 (random.x, 0, random.z);

     newSpawnPoint += transform.position;

     if (!spawnPoints.Contains (newSpawnPoint)) {
         return newSpawnPoint;
         spawnPoints.Add (newSpawnPoint);
         int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Count);
         Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints [spawnIndex].normalized, Quaternion.identity);  //Spawn randomly
     } else {
         return Vector3.zero;}}
```

The problem is enemy is not spawning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you spawning it in  spawnPoints [spawnIndex].normalized?
you should spawn it in newSpawnPoint.

The first statement in your if block is a return statement.
move it to be the last one.

hope it helps

Comment: I wrote newSpawnPoint[spawnIndex]**.** . After that, which method should I use? see the image. 
**Instantiate** argument #2 takes Transform, not Vector3.
[Image](https://ibb.co/27s3GmB)

Comment: You wrote:

Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints [spawnIndex].normalized, Quaternion.identity);


it means you are using 1 of the overloads of Instantiate but it is the one who gets Object, Vector3, Quaternioin)

see doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

and besides you need to instantiate it in the new place meaning newSpawnPoint 

hope it helps

Comment: Yes, you're right! But what am I supposed to write after newSpawnPoint[spawnIndex]. ?
I couldn't figure out the alternate way to write it. 
I hope you understand!

Comment: you should use:
Instantiate (enemy, newSpawnPoint , Quaternion.identity);

Thats it.

Comment: I tried! It doesn't work! I tried using Transform instead of Vector3 but it gave me errors. Any other approach towards this problem?

Comment: What is the error or output you get that does not meet your expectation?

Comment: Inside your if the first statement is return.after that your method ends. I missed it before. Move it to be your last statement inside the if block

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Edit your previous answer, then I'll mark it as correct! 

Comment: Edited, Thanks 